# Llenar automáticamente otro campo

Tags: php, javascript, html

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="inputBox">
                  <div class="inputText">*Puesto</div>
                     <select class="input"  name="puesto" required>
                      <option value="" disabled selected></option>
                      <option value="1">Gerente</option>
                      <option value="2">Vendedor</option>
                      <option value="3">Vendedor Comisionista</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
```

Hay alguna manera de rellenar automáticamente un campo con los datos de ese `select`?.

Por ejemplo si yo escojo gerente que un `input text` se llene solo con la palabra gerente; esto porque los datos que me guarda son los del `value` y no los de gerente...,etc.

Me dirán que cambie los datos del `value` pero necesito los dos datos.

Comment: si con onchange creo que se puede

Comment: Tienes el dato exacto de como, amigo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando `jQuery` es posible, en donde detectamos el cambio en el `select` y le asignamos al `input`

```js
$(document).on("change","#puesto",function(e){
  var txt=$("#puesto option:selected").text();
  $("#texto").val(txt);
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="inputBox">
          <div class="inputText">*Puesto</div>
             <select id="puesto" class="input"  name="puesto" required>
              <option value="" disabled selected></option>
              <option value="1">Gerente</option>
              <option value="2">Vendedor</option>
              <option value="3">Vendedor Comisionista</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        Mostrando en un input
        <br>
        <input id="texto" type="text" />
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Con jQuery es muy sencillo usando `text()` asi:

```js
$(".puesto").on("change", function() {
  $("#puesto").val($("option:selected", this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="inputBox">
                  <div class="inputText">*Puesto</div>
                     <select class="input puesto"  name="puesto" required>
                      <option value="" disabled selected></option>
                      <option value="1">Gerente</option>
                      <option value="2">Vendedor</option>
                      <option value="3">Vendedor Comisionista</option>
                    </select>
                    <input id="puesto">
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si necesitas los dos valores tanto el `value` como el texto de la opción con JS puro tomas el valor con `value` y su texto con `innerHTML`, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
const puesto = document.getElementById('puesto');


puesto.addEventListener('change', (e)=>{
console.log(`Esto es el texto: ${puesto.options[puesto.selectedIndex].innerHTML} y este su valor: ${puesto.options[puesto.selectedIndex].value} `);

})
```

```html
<select class="input" id="puesto"  name="puesto" required>
                      <option value="" disabled selected></option>
                      <option value="1">Gerente</option>
                      <option value="2">Vendedor</option>
                      <option value="3">Vendedor Comisionista</option>
                    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

¿ Y por qué no añades los dos como `value` ?

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="inputBox">
        <div class="inputText">*Puesto</div>
                <select class="input"  name="puesto" required>
                <option value="" disabled selected></option>
                <option value="1:gerente">Gerente</option>
                <option value="2:vendedor">Vendedor</option>
                <option value="3:comisionista">Vendedor Comisionista</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Luego, desde `PHP`, obtienes ambos datos:

```php
<?php
list($id, $puesto) = explode(':', $_POST['puesto']);
```

O también puedes obtener ambos desde `javascript`:

```
var value = document.getElementByName('puesto').value.split(':');
var id = value[0];
var puesto = value[1];
```

Comment: El OP aclara en su pregunta que no le vale cambiar los datos del `value`.

Comment: Quizás lo entendí mal, pero yo entiendo que se refiere a no poner las etiquetas como value. Ya que haciendo eso también le haría falta el id de las etiquetas. De la forma que propongo tiene los dos valores que es lo que él necesita.